# How to put an image thumbnail in Sharepoint list element from Power automate with API Query

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, power-automate

Hi everyone i try to achieve to put/update an image thumbnail field from a power automate.
What my flow look like is

[image]

1. receive a http payload with base64image content and image name
2. Create in site/list/attachement folder the image

So far so good i succefully create an image in my site document folder

3. i get the thumbnail data for my element with a sharepoint http request

```
METHODS: GET
URI: _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<MyListName>')/items(2)?$select=Thumbnail_image
```

i receive as response

```
"body": {
        "d": {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "e160a1f1-6877-4dcd-b913-cc96a3811c37",
                "uri": "https://<tenantname>/sites/<sitename>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'e3fae353-d412-400e-a49e-14009935e706')/Items(2)",
                "etag": "\"28\"",
                "type": "SP.Data.<sitename>ListItem"
            },
            "Thumbnail_image": "{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"tmp_to_delete_ thumbnail.png\",\"nativeFile\":{},\"fieldName\":\"Thumbnail_image\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://<tenantname>\",\"fieldId\":\"6986c538-e002-489c-afe4-e6004c65d991\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/<sitename>/Lists/e3fae353-d412-400e-a49e-14009935e706/tmp_to_delete_thumbnail2.png\",\"id\":\"eb3be415-caa4-40d7-8ce3-24cbae608163\"}"
        }
    }
```

from here i tryed to use a PUT and PATCH method on the Items and replace values and url with those corresponding to my new image but my request failed

how can i from here change or add my image in the thumbnail field?
thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action like below:

[image]

Body Payload Example:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.ImageListListItem"
    },
    "Title": "Power Automate",
    "Image": "{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"power-automate.png\",\"nativeFile\":{},\"fieldName\":\"Image\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://contoso.sharepoint.com\",\"fieldId\":\"27bfae8e-6eb8-434a-b266-8b41249d38c1\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/Lists/dbc6f551-252b-462f-8002-c8f88d0d12d5/power-automate.png\",\"id\":\"eec83dc9-26b5-44cb-8222-64ca4a33fd11\"}"
}
```

**Additional Info**: [Add/Change image on a SharePoint List image column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292558/add-change-image-on-a-sharepoint-list-image-column/292561#292561)